# Event based editor like in StarCraft 2 Editor (algorithm)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, events, editor

**I'm trying to create an algorithm for an `event based editor` like in StarCraft 2 Editor that can support:**

- Create UI
- Play sounds
- Handle keyboard/mouse inputs
- Display messages
- Button(or some referenced UI object) is pressed   etc.

**Pretty much the same thing as in StarCraft 2 Editor (of course not the 3D stuff too)**

---

So far I'm thinking to use `JSON` , add every event in an object and then loop through them and create an event using the `addEventListener()` method.

**The JSON Events Object**(of course it will be created by the user in the editor with no programming):

```
var Events={
    //your event's names here
    onReady:{ //on page ready to manipulate
        displayMessage:{//just a simple popup
            text:"Hello user!",
            title:"Welcome!",
            type:"normal",
            },
        createButton:{ //creates a buton on the screen
            text:"Click me!",
            id:"myButton"
        }
    },
    onClick:{
        id:"myButton" ,//the id of the button we just created
        actions:{ //the actions applied after we click the button
            displayMessage:{//just a simple popup
                text:"You pressed me!",
                title:"Button",
                type:"error",//show the message as an error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found some softwares **([GameMaker](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/studio),[Construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/construct2),[GameDevelop](http://www.compilgames.net/))** that have an **`event based editor`** if you would like to get an idea about what I'm talking about (if you don't already know about StarCraft 2 Editor)

My question is:
**What is the best algorithm that I can use to achieve this?**

Comment: The problem with this is that you cant have multiple callback bound to 1 event, it also causes lots of configuration and endless levels of indentation.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

When the user creates a custom area in your editor all it's attributes are stored inside an object (that you can save as JSON) that would then be applied to a div as param when loading the map (using [html-attributes](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

```
function create_areas(areas){
    var map = $('#map_area');
    for(var i=0;i<areas.length;i++){
        map.append($('<div>', area[i].params));
    }
}
```

whereas params would look something like this:

```
params = {
    width: 100,
    height: 200,
    ....
    mousedown: function(){ play_music('hello'); },
    keydown: function(e){ alert('you pressed ' + e.keyCode; }
}
```

also the jQuery UI tools like [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [resizeable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) should ease up building your editor.

Answer (score 3):

I'd model this more after backbone's event system:

```
events: {
  'click selector': handler,
  'mouseover selector': handler2,
  ...
}
```

Handlers can be any javascript function, this would allow you to create a bunch of pre-defined functions like `displayMessage`.

Then you could curry your own handlers, which would allow your users to specify configuration if they need it.

Example:

```
var events = {
   'click element': displayMessage({
        text:"Hello user!",
        title:"Welcome!",
        type:"normal",
    }),
   'mouseover pizza': createButton({...}) 
}

function displayMessage(options) {
   var options = options;

   return function() {
      //display message logic
   }
}
```

Then you can supply a `compose` function among other helpers (look up promises perhaps?) to combine your functions together:

```
var events = {
   'click element': compose(
        displayMessage({
            text:"Hello user!",
            title:"Welcome!",
            type:"normal",
        }),
        createButton({})
    ),
   'mouseover pizza': createButton({...}) 
}
```

This could work out?

Caveat: it might be better if events was an array that contained objects. That way you can have multiple click handlers on some selector without collisions.

Comment: Sorry.I forgot to mention I don't want to work with frameworks (1.I don't like them ,2.I want to make everything from scratch)

Comment: @boyd I wasn't advocating to use backbone, but rather take inspiration from it. The example you showed looks a lot like backbone.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see this there are really severall choices you need to make. I would, although I prefer JSON as a data construct not limit myself to this subset of an actuall programming language. And engener this the other way around.

You have events, handlers and options. Where a option, or better a option list is the user inputed data, the handlers are the actual action, and the events are triggers to set some action off.

If you read this carefully you will notice this is the exact description of the basic structure of most jQuery-Scripts or Event-Driven Software in generall. Only the users options in jQuery are (since it is a DOM Framework) most often the context of a single DOM-Element. So, here we are and I would suggest to simply borrow the theorie behind this and make use of [promisses](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/JavascriptPromise.html) wich make a very [clear](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics) and great way to generate code!

So my call to any event chain would look like this.

```
...when(chainObject['event'])
.then(function(event) {
      //call handler
      handlers[chainObject[selectedHandler]].call(event.context, chainObject['options']); 
      //apply next element(s) in chain, this is the current promise
      appendNextElement(chainObject['followingHandlers'], this);
})...
```

Notice how `apply` makes it easy for you to change the environement and in turn behaviour of any hanlder based on what the user and event did. And promisses make error handling very easy!

This of course applies to only one node in your chain. So what should a data structure look like to let you generate this kind of code?

One node in your structure would look like this:

```
   {
      event: 'click',
      selectedHandler: 'sohwText',
      options: {
          'text': 'helloWorld'
      },
      followingChain: {...OTHER HANDLERS....}
   }
```

The important thing to notice is that like a good structured functional programm you are looking at a tree and not at a simple list of events. So every actual DOM Element holds many of these

```
var eventTree = {
   '.someButton': [..Handlers of this button...],'
   '.someOtherButton': [..Handlers of the other button...],
}
```

And there we go. You have a context (the button), a event, user input and a handler.

The resulting app should not only work, but will be styled for any experienced JavaScript-Programmer to expand or mod.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand this 'promise' thing because I didn't worked with it.Can you make a simple jsfiddle:when I click a div move it to 500px top,and 500 px left {event:click,element:div,action:moveTo(500,500)} using your algorithm?

Comment: I have mentioned the promise, because it will give you the central idea behind event handling in most modern javascript librarys -> thus giving you the teoretical background to master your task. The problem is, that showing you an example in your domain would most certainly be the complete solution to your question - and this would mean quite a few lines of code... wich i will not be able to produce anytime soon. sorry